# Convert JSON table horizontally

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I am able to scrape the table using Python Selenium and save the file in JSON format. But the JSON is in vertical manner. I want it to scrape the tables horizontally.

Below is my python code snippet:

```py
rooms_table = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table[id='no-more-tables']")
df = pd.read_html(str(rooms_table.get_attribute('outerHTML')))
tables = df[0]
print(tables)

to_json_table = tables.to_json()
result['rooms'] = []
room_dict = {}

print(to_json_table)
```

My output:

```json
{
    "ROOM TYPE": {
        "0": "Bronze Studio",
        "1": "Silver Studio",
        "2": "Silver Studio",
        "3": "Gold Studio"
    },
    "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": {
        "0": null,
        "1": "\u00a3134",
        "2": "\u00a3147",
        "3": "\u00a3167"
    },
    "WEEKS": {
        "0": null,
        "1": 51.0,
        "2": 44.0,
        "3": 51.0
    },
    "START DATE": {
        "0": null,
        "1": "27\/08\/22",
        "2": "27\/08\/22",
        "3": "27\/08\/22"
    },
    "AVAILABILITY": {
        "0": "Sold Out",
        "1": "Available - Book Now",
        "2": "Last few remaining - book now",
        "3": "Last few remaining - book now"
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```json
{
    "0": {
        "ROOM TYPE": "Bronze Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": null,
        "WEEKS": null,
        "START DATE": null,
        "AVAILABILITY": "Sold Out"
    },
    "1": {
        "ROOM TYPE": "Silver Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": "\u00a3134",
        "WEEKS": 51.0,
        "START DATE": "27\/08\/22",
        "AVAILABILITY": "Available - Book Now"
    },
    "2": {
        "ROOM TYPE": "Silver Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": "\u00a3147",
        "WEEKS": 44.0,
        "START DATE": "27\/08\/22",
        "AVAILABILITY": "Last few remaining - book now"
    },
    "3": {
        "ROOM TYPE": "Gold Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": "\u00a3167",
        "WEEKS": 51.0,
        "START DATE": "27\/08\/22",
        "AVAILABILITY": "Last few remaining - book now"
    }
}
```

What code should I write to solve this?

Comment: What table? how do you scrape it? from where the extra data is coming? you need to provide [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Guy I am scraping the table from this link -     https://www.hellostudent.co.uk/student-accommodation/aberdeen/centro-court/'

Comment: It looks like what you want to do is *transpose* the data in the table — so search for that term.

Comment: @martineau can you again see the question?

I've made some changes.

Comment: @Guy can you again see the question? I've made some changes.

Comment: @platipus_on_fire can you help here?

Answer (score 0):

The `to_json()` method has an `orient` parameter, so changing `to_json_table = tables.to_json(orient="index")` in your code should give you:

```json
{
    "0": {
        "ROOM TYPE"                 : "Bronze Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": null,
        "WEEKS"                     : null,
        "START DATE"                : null,
        "AVAILABILITY"              : "Sold Out"
    },
    "1": {
        "ROOM TYPE"                 : "Silver Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": "\u00a3134",
        "WEEKS"                     : 51.0,
        "START DATE"                : "27\/08\/22",
        "AVAILABILITY"              : "Available - Book Now"
    },
    "2": {
        "ROOM TYPE"                 : "Silver Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": "\u00a3147",
        "WEEKS"                     : 44.0,
        "START DATE"                : "27\/08\/22",
        "AVAILABILITY"              : "Last few remaining - book now"
    },
    "3": {
        "ROOM TYPE"                 : "Gold Studio",
        "PRICE PER WEEK\/PER PERSON": "\u00a3167",
        "WEEKS"                     : 51.0,
        "START DATE"                : "27\/08\/22",
        "AVAILABILITY"              : "Last few remaining - book now"
    }
}
```